# converting arrays from string to datetime

Tags: php, datetime

Is there an efficient way to convert the format of an array of dates from string into DateTime?

I have an array of DateTimes and an array of dates in string format (i.e. "2017-01-01"). I need to use "array_intersect" to determine which records from each of the arrays match but they must both be in DateTime format for that to work.

Comment: Using [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) perhaps? `array_walk($myArray, function(&$value) { $value = new DateTime($value); });`

Comment: @MarkBaker ITYM `array_map()` - better generally not to mutate the original array

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the strings like so...

```
foreach($dateStrings as $dateString){
    $dates[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateString);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: looks good... but what do $dateStrings and $dateString and $dates represent?

Comment: $dateStrings would be the array of dates in string format. $dates would be the resultant array of dateTime formatted elements, that you can intersect with your existing array of DateTimes.

Answer (score 0):

Since `array_intersect` actually compares the string values of the objects inside the array, I would convert the other way around: from DateTime to string. This might look as follows:

```
<?php

// Suppose you have these DateTime objects
$toConvert = [
    DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2012-04-22'),
    DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2012-05-10'),
    DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-06-03'),
];

$dateStrings1 = ['2012-04-22', '2012-05-10', '2015-05-05'];

$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';

// Convert the array of DateTime objects to strings
$dateStrings2 = array_map(function($dateTime) use ($dateFormat) {
    return $dateTime->format($dateFormat);
}, $toConvert);

$intersection = array_intersect($dateStrings1, $dateStrings2);

var_dump($intersection);
```

The output of this is:

`array (size=2)
  0 => string '2012-04-22' (length=10)
  1 => string '2012-05-10' (length=10)`